# Second order ordinary differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the following ODE:

$$ \frac{f''(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{a''(x)}{a(x)}, $$

where $a(x)$ is a well behaved function. It is easy to check that the solution is given by

$$ f(x)=C a(x) + D a(x) \int \frac{\mathrm{dx}}{a^2(x)},$$

where $C$ and $D$ are constants.

Do you have any ideas about how to get this result from direct computations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=a(x)y$. Then 
$$ f''(x)=a(x)y''+2a'(x)y'+a''(x)y $$
and hence
$$ \frac{a(x)y''+2a'(x)y'+a''(x)y}{a(x)y}=\frac{a''(x)}{a(x)} $$
After simplifying, we have
$$ a(x)y''+2a'(x)y'=0. $$
Now it is not hard to solve for $y$ and hence the solution of the original DE. You can do the rest.